# Is it possibile select one element at time in pick list prime ng

Tags: angular, primeng, picklist

I need to do my pick list one selected. The default behavior is when the user click on more items (source panel) it selects all and pass them in the target panel.
I want the when the user click on source items it can selected only one item. This is my html code:

```
p-pickList [responsive]="true" sourceHeader="Prov" targetHeader="Ass" [source]="list1" [target]="lis2" [metaKeySelection]="false" >
```

I don't know what property  I need to use. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Multiple items can only be selected when you press the `Meta`, `Ctrl` or `Shift` key. Do you want to disable this feature?

Comment: @MichaelD yeah! How I can do this?

Comment: I don't think there is an built-in way for it. You could however extend the PickList and remove the mechanism manually.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need an answer I've just found a simple way to do unique selection with PrimeNG PickList.

HTML:

```
<p-pickList
    [metaKeySelection]="false"
    (onSourceSelect)="onElementSelect($event)"
>
    <ng-template let-element Template="item">
        <span>
            {{ element }}
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Typescript :

```
// Make the PickList not multiple
public onElementSelect(event): void {
    if (event.items.length > 1) {
        event.items.splice(0, event.items.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```html
 <p-pickList #listPickerCtrl                   
   (onSourceSelect)="onSourceSelect($event)"
   (onTargetSelect)="onTargetSelect($event)">
 </p-pickList>
```

```js
import { PickList } from 'primeng/picklist';

@ViewChild('listPickerCtrl') listPickerCtrl: PickList;

onSourceSelect(args: any) {
    // Disable multiple selection
    if (args.items.length > 1) {
      const lastItemIndex = args.items.length - 1;
      if (lastItemIndex > -1) {
        this.listPickerCtrl.selectedItemsSource.splice(lastItemIndex, 1);
      }
    }
  }

 onTargetSelect(args: any) {
    // Disable multiple selection
    if (args.items.length > 1) {
      const lastItemIndex = args.items.length - 1;
      if (lastItemIndex > -1) {
        this.listPickerCtrl.selectedItemsTarget.splice(lastItemIndex, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```